# how to get a JTextField to check if the text is equal to an int

Tags: java, swing, int, jtextfield

I'm making a program where you type in a number and it will either tell you if you got it right or wrong. This is the code.

```
static int num = 1;

JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        JTextField numSlot = new JTextField(5);
        pnl.add(new JLabel("Enter the number:"));
        pnl.add(numSlot);

        int k = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pnl, "Enter your code", -1);
        if (k == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

            if(numSlot.getText().equals(num)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It Worked", "It Worked", -1);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry", "Sorry", -1);
            }
        }
        if (k == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {

        } else {

        }
```

With this code it always outputs sorry even if i type 1 so is there something i'm doing wrong? If so could you answer it and try not to be rude i am a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
if(numSlot.getText().equals(num+"")){
```

instead of

```
if(numSlot.getText().equals(num)) {
```

as `num+""` convert it `int` to `String`. 
Otherway you can use `Integer.toString(num)` or `String.valueOf(num)`

**Explanation**

`numSlot.getText()` return String and `num` is int so `numSlot.getText().equals(num)` always false as String value can not be same as integer value.